# ping server when the app is in background

Tags: ios, multitasking

I need to keep the app to send a simple GET request ("ping") to the server every minute just for it to know that user is still online. I have no problem with it while the app is active and 10 minutes after it went background using "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler".

But how can I keep request repeated all the time unless user terminates app manually?

Comment: @Maksam: i didnt getting you clearly. where are you getting problem while background or while terminating app? can you please clear me

Comment: @debugger: Thanks for your interest, debugger. I need my app to ping server all the time with the GET request. But it stops 10 minutes after it has been sent to background. My question is there any way to keep it alive all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really how it works -- it's not a Windows or a Mac app that runs continually in the background.

What you probably want to do is use the [background fetch process](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html), whereby iOS will periodically run a particular method allowing you to do network operations while your app is in the background (or not running at all).

What this won't allow you to do is ping your server exactly once every minute. But actually that's a good thing. Consuming a users battery and data allowance like that is not very user-friendly.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Do I understand it right that performFetchWithCompletionHandler is being called repeatedly as often as system allows to the application? I do not need to create a timer or or any other loops to keep it alive, but the system might call it once in an hour or longer.

Comment: Correct. You give it the _minimum_ period between calls but the OS decides exactly when and how often.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me very good as user will start an app once or twice a day (the performFetchWithCompletionHandler will be called to rarely), but the server require to "know" wether the user is online or not all the time with at least once in 10 minutes refresh(ping or any other way). Can you advise anything on it?

Comment: You may be able to use push notifications (specifically the new `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method) but I don't know if there is any limitation on frequency.

Comment: But even if that works, see my last paragraph. Your app better be _really_ compelling as you're going to really impact a devices battery life.